# On Windows 7 can one make UAC on an admin account prompt for the password, just like a limited account?

Tags: windows-7, uac

I am one of the very few who likes the security of UAC and so I have the UAC set to "Always Notify" on my Admin account. But I would be even happier if the system would prompt me for a password, when notifying me.

I can get what I want by adding a second non-admin user and using that account.

But somehow it seems wasteful to have two accounts set up when I will always use the non-admin account day-to-day.

So I am wondering if there is any setting that would cause an Admin account to behave password-prompting-wise as a standard account?

Comment: Why do you want to have to type your password in? It's not more secure - applications can't interface with the UAC dialogues.

Comment: Too easy to just hit OK. Entering a password adds a few moments of sober second thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I love UAC as well! (Well, love maybe to strong... I wish a *few* things were different, but I like it a lot!)

Anyway, to do what you want, simply launch `Local Group Policy Editor` (Run > `gpedit.msc`) and expand `Local Computer Policy > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options` Scroll to the bottom of the content window and look for `User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrator in Admin Approval Mode` and change it from `Prompt for consent` to `Prompt for credentials` or whatever settings you want.

[image]

There are a bunch of other UAC related options, Take a look - you may find something else you want to change!

Comment: GodMode (what's next?) is another way to open the group policy editor (and a LOT more): create a new folder (e.g. on the desktop) and name it as follows: GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}

Comment: @Molly - It's not God Mode!... You can write ANYTHING, it is a GUID shortcut to all the tool tips from control panel.

Comment: I am running Windows 7 Home Premium. Do I have a group policy editor? Can't seem to find it. By the way, GodMode is mega-cool!

Comment: i know, Wil, you can name it anything you want (before the dot), but GodMode sounds funny :)

Comment: @ Bill: the Local Group Policy editor (gpedit.msc) is not available in the Windows 7 Home Premium

Comment: @Bill: what you can try: exctract the file INSTALL.WIM from the Windows 7 DVD with Universal Extractor, if you find GPEDIT.MSC, copy the file to Windows\System32.

Comment: @Bill, try going in to control panel > administration tools > local security policy... then it should be in a similar path but start at security settings.... gpedit.msc basically takes a few things from a few places and makes it easier in one place.

Comment: @Wil: No "local security policy" either. @Molly: Tried your suggestion, with no luck. I was thinking of upgrading to "Professional", anyway, so this may be another reason to do it. I hate products with multiple tiers: huge support issues. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Bill - in all honestly, I have only used XP, Vista and 7 in the professional, enterprise or ultimate editions... I can usually support the others as they are so similar but I had no idea that this feature was not on the others. Please check back soon (really busy at the moment) and I will try to install home premium inside a VM and see if I can recommend anything.

Comment: You don't need the group policy editor to change this. It's a registry setting which you can change manually.


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:00000001

Comment: @WilliamHilsum any luck with doing this on Home Editions? I really want to get this to work! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have Vista or Windows 7 Professional then, as others have noted, you won't have `secpol.msc` and so there is no interface for adjusting the relevant settings. However, you can still change them with the trusty old Registry Editor.

The relevant values may be found under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`, and are as follows.

- `ConsentPromptBehaviourAdmin`: set this to `3` (prompt for credentials) or `1` (prompt for credentials on secure desktop)
- `ConsentPromptBehaviourUser`: set this to `3` (prompt for credentials) or `1` (prompt for credentials on secure desktop)
- `PromptOnSecureDesktop`: where the previous two values are set to `3`, this will cause their prompts to appear on the secure desktop; if the previous two values are `1`, then this setting is ignored.

Finally, here is Microsoft's own documentation for these keys: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_RegistryKeys. IMO their documentation does not make explicit enough the effect of `PromptOnSecureDesktop` on the other two options that I list above. The key upsight is that, where the documentation says "prompt for {consent,credentials}" without explicitly saying "on the secure desktop", the value of `PromptOnSecureDesktop` determines whether the user is switched to the secure desktop for prompting.

Comment: +1 Accepted answer didn't work for me on Windows 8.1 (gpedit.msc not found), but editing registry key worked.