# Require password for installing Windows applications on Admin account

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-8

I am trying to emulate some of the security I've noticed on Linux onto my Windows 8 machine. I really like that on my Ubuntu install, any time that I change anything potentially harmful (install software, configure settings etc) it will request a password on that account. I want to do this on Windows, but there seems to be a general process that most people will do.

1. Create an admin account
2. Create your a second account that is essentially the "main" account.
3. Set the second account to be a limited account

Is there a way to require this for the admin account as well? I feel as though Windows is a great system, but it is too easy for things to be installed without noticing them and I feel like this would stop it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar exists in Windows, it's called User Account Control ([UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control)).

If you have it turned on/up, then Windows will make you OK any system-level changes before making them.

> When changes are going to be made to your computer that require administrator-level permission, UAC notifies you. If you are an administrator, you can click Yes to continue. If you are not an administrator, someone with an administrator account on the computer will have to enter their password for you to continue.

[MS source, and more info here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/what-is-user-account-control#1TC=windows-7)

For info on making UAC act more like SUDO (in that it asks for a password even if your an admin), check out this SU question: [On Windows 7 can one make UAC on an admin account prompt for the password, just like a limited account?](https://superuser.com/questions/91357/on-windows-7-can-one-make-uac-on-an-admin-account-prompt-for-the-password-just?rq=1)