# Require password on elevate in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, uac

I'm setting up a new laptop that has Windows 8.1 installed. What I'd like to do: require the account password to be entered whenever I get an elevate prompt ("Allow the following program to make changes to your system?").

My main use case is that I want to let my kids use my laptop, but ensure that they can't install programs or change settings. I know I could give them a separate login with lower permissions, but I'd rather just have one login.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, that question answered my question. thanks!

Comment: This is simple.  Use a normal `User` account.

Answer (score 4):

If the account you set up for your kids is a `User` account instead of an `Administrator` account it will behave exactly are you wanting it to behave.

There is no way to do it with one login unless you want to make your everyday account not a administrator and have separate hidden administrator account.

EDIT: I was wrong, you can have it prompt for credentials, [it is a change of the local security policy](https://superuser.com/questions/91357/on-windows-7-can-one-make-uac-on-an-admin-account-prompt-for-the-password-just). Just change `Prompt for consent` to `Prompt for credentials` for the securit setting `User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrator in Admin Approval Mode`

Comment: I was able to do it using the answers on the duplicate question. Required some regedit action though.