# Why does UAC prompt for a password instead of yes/no?

Tags: windows-10, uac

Until today, when I started Command Prompt as an administrator, I would get a yes/no prompt like (image copied from web):

[image]

Today when I start a Command Prompt as administrator, I get a prompt like this (the one I get also allows me to enter a PIN):

[image]

What controls whether Windows 10 presents a UAC yes/no prompt versus a UAC password/pin prompt?

Comment: Just to verify your user is in the Administrators group?

Comment: @MrStatic: Yes it is. I can use the same account/password to log in and for the UAC popup

Comment: What does your local/group policy say: http://superuser.com/questions/91357/on-windows-7-can-one-make-uac-on-an-admin-account-prompt-for-the-password-just

Comment: @BigChris: "Prompt for consent for non-Windows binaries"

Answer (score 6):

From the answer linked by BigChris, it looks like the yes/no prompt is called "Admin Approval Mode".

This is controlled through the local policy.  Launch `Local Group Policy Editor` (Run > `gpedit.msc`) and expand `Local Computer Policy > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options`. Scroll to the bottom of the content window and look for `User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode`.

In my case, I removed and added my account to the administrators group.  After that you have to logout and log back in to get the UAC prompt without the password.

Answer (score 5):

Further to Andomar's answer, another setting you can change instead (in the same location) is `User Account Control: Behaviour of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode`.

The options are:

- Elevate without prompting
- Prompt for credentials on the secure desktop
- Prompt for consent on the secure desktop
- Prompt for credentials
- Prompt for consent
- Prompt for consent for non-Windows binaries

I believe the options "Prompt for consent on the secure desktop" or