# Logged in as Admin, yet file operations need "as Admin" confirmation [Win 7]

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator

I am logged in through the only account defined on my new Windows 7 Professional PC. Despite it being a (password-protected) administrator account, every time I need to copy files on the C: system partition,  install software, run Regedit, etc, Windows comes up with an extra confirmation screen, to get past which I have to choose the "As Administrator" button - the operation then proceeds as normal, it's just annoying that the confirmation screen is always there.

Also, several programs that I would like to have integrated in the Windows context (right click) menus cannot be integrated, presumably because  of the same ambiguity with regards to the Administrator status of the account - and then there is no prompting from Windows, making these program unable to operate as expected.

On my old Win7 PC, my Admin account appeared to have been configured in exactly the same way, yet I did not have these problems, and I was able to do any file operations, including in system folders such as \Program Files or \Windows. What shall I do? Thanks!

Comment: What you describe is normal

Comment: Don't log-in as admin and only elevate when you need to. Yes, whenever you need to elevate you provide credentials / another confirmation step.

Comment: "I was able to do any file operations, including in system folders such as \Program Files or \Windows" this is a problem that you have fixed. Congratulations. Now if you do accidentally run a malicious program its damage is mitigated.

Comment: Still, how can programs that need to add options to the right-click menu of drives/files/folders receive the necessary access? And how can I not get the Admin warning every single time, since I *am* logged in as Admin?

Comment: @longtalker - What?  If the programs need Administrator access then you elevate their access, that is done through a UAC prompt, 99% of the time programs don't need Administrator access though.  Writing to C:\ is actually really bad, writing to the specific folders that don't require elevated access is good.

Comment: So what might I [inadvertendly] have done to not have the UAC prompts on my old PC?

Comment: Also, I am still without a response as to how I can have software such as Unlocker add a command to rclick menus

Comment: You probably turned off the UAC (prompts).  Go look at your UAC settings.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that other question, I learnt smth useful about UAC. But once again, even after reading the answers there, I still don't know what to do to enable my programs to work as intended. I gave the example of Unlocker, a startup utility that adds an Unlock option to the rclick menu of files and drivers in order to free them from any hidden program that might be holding them open. Another is Total Commander, which reports that it cannot save its settings in the \program files\totalcmd\settings.ini file; what do i need to do? My UAC settings is at the Standard slider position.

Comment: I'd suggest that you reword your question a bit, which could help other users and yourself.  Ask how you can easily elevate certain events and processes, while retaining your current UAC prompts.  

One answer is to start with making a simple shortcut when running as administrator:  
Go to properties, Advanced, and then check, "run as administrator".  That shortcut will elevate any EXE's, batch files, and other processes that would normally require a UAC prompt, or not run at all.  (This only works when running as an administrator).

Comment: @longtalker http://superuser.com/a/1064534/53590 looks relevant to the final paragraph of your question.

Comment: Thanks. Following your advice, I now solved all problems except for the Unlocker app, which will not appear in my right click menus even though I run it as Admin, and respond to UAC prompts appropriately.